# NestJs TypeOrm Custom Repository Unit Test Case

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

My nestjs project uses typeorm custom repositories.

```
@EntityRepository(MyEntity)
export class MyRepository extends AbstractRepository<MyEntity> {
    
    public operation1(entity) {

        /**
         * Few lines here   
        */
        this.manager.save(entity);
    }
 }
```

I am trying to write unit testcases using jest for the method operation1, But I am not able to mock this.manager.*.
Is there a way to mock this.manager.* methods?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jest. Let's try this way:

```
let myRepository: Repository<MyRepository>;

jest
  .spyOn(myRepository, 'manage')
  .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(entity);
```